# Does powershell have the ability to run tasks?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there an equivalent to Powershell make?  The equivalent of make/[rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake)/[cake](https://cakebuild.net/)/py-make, even Gulp...etc?  I primarily desire a task runner for build automation.  I want to be able to select and compose tasks like I can in [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).

Ideally, the solution would be native to Powershell.  There are very tight security restrictions on software installations for the project.  The power of Google has failed me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nothing built-in, but there are different solutions like [psake](https://github.com/psake/psake) or [invoke-build](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build). maybe something else.

You can also use VScode for that, you can define tasks (basically run scripts or something) and run them on save or on check out, etc

Comment: Thanks for the VSCode suggestion.  I had no idea I VSCode supported tasks.  That will work.  More info for the sake of others:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks